# Spring batch execute query before start process

Tags: database, process, spring-batch

I use Spring Batch in my application. I have a requirement in which i need to execute an update query on the database before start processing the rows. After the reading, in the mapping phase I populate a list according to the data i read from dataBase,
and before i start the process i need to update a table in database according to this list.
this query need to be executed only once, and this is why the method beforeProcess() is not relevant as it is called for every row.

Comment: Your requirements aren't very clear but I think you could separate the pre-reading update query into a tasklet step. If I understood right you need to trigger another update after reading the first chunk (the job commit-interval seems to be set to 1). This query could be isolated within a separate tasklet step too. An less elegant solution could be implement a condition on the processor or create a separate processor do to this (but you will have to worry about managing this value on restart scenario).

Comment: performing it in a separate tasklet sounds like a good approach, the thing is i need to use the result of the reader query. because of that i think a second processor that will perform only the update query will be better. can u suggest how can i define multiple processors for one reader and their order of execution? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you choose the CompositeItemProcessor approach you wil have to perform an if statement to return null if it's not the first read. So you will have unnecessary condition verification for all your database rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain processors with a `CompositeItemProcessor` :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor">
    <property name="delegates">
        <list>
            <bean class="xx.xx.xx.UpdateDatabaseProcessor"></bean>
            <bean class="xx.xx.xx.CurrentProcessor"></bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

They will be executed in the order of their declaration.